# How to query data efficiently in large Cassandra collection?

Tags: node.js, cassandra-2.0

I have one big Casandra collection (1-million docs), and I want to query the whole user table data its around 1 million records. When I run following query its only return around 10K records.

Could you please let me know what is the effective method to query whole documents from Casandra collection

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cassandra-driver npm as casandra driver

```
 Tried 

  const query = 'select * from users';
  db.users.executeQuery(query)
  .then(function (result2) {

  })
  .catch (function (error) {
    reject(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you cannot retrieve all the data at once is because there is a limit on the number of item you can read at once which is understandable.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.0/features/paging/) you sould use of the `stream` or `eachRow` methods. Which allow you to get treat the entries of the collection in multiple iterations.

---

```
client.stream(query, parameters, options)
  .on('readable', function () {
    // readable is emitted as soon a row is received and parsed
    let row;
    while (row = this.read()) {
      // process row
    }
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    // emitted when all rows have been retrieved and read
  });
```

Or

```
client.eachRow(query, parameters, { prepare: true, autoPage : true }, function(n, row) {
   // Invoked per each row in all the pages
}, callback);
```

Comment: Thank you @Grégory NEUT it really helps.